# MySQL 8: Incorrect datetime value: '$VARIANT$' for function str_to_date

Tags: mysql, sql, jaspersoft-studio

I took over an old SQL query that includes the following expression:

```
SELECT 
g.Citystate,
g.Cityorder,
if(CityPostal is null, CityName, concat(CityName, ', ', CityPostal)) as CityName,
g.CityName as CityAdress,
g.CityKey,
@Published = ifnull(if (g.CityKey='S',
(SELECT sum(if(FROM_UNIXTIME(g1.Timestamp/1000) >= STR_TO_DATE('$VARIANT$', '%e.%m.%Y'), g1.Published, 0))
from PUBLISHED_DATA g1
```

If I execute the whole SQL Statement in DBeaver I get the following error:
`Incorrect datetime value: '$VARIANT$' for function str_to_date`

I think the error occures because the syntax did not work with the newest MySQl version.

The query works if I pass a static string like "01.01.1971" as first argument to the `STR_TO_DATE` function. I'm searching for how to set up dynamic variable names, but I didn't find any solution. What does `$VARIANT$` exactly mean? Does it define a parameter?

Comment: MySQL Server doesn't parse string literals looking for parameters. Is there any client language or preprocessor that may be preparing the SQL code?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: The query is used in Jaspersoft. A parameter like `$VARIANT$` is there also defined. If I replace `$VARIANT$` with `$P{Variant}` I get the error: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (11 > number of parameters, which is 10).`

Comment: There you are your answer. It isn't plain SQL, so you cannot execute it with DBeaver.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Thank you! But is `$VARIANT$` the correct syntax? What does it mean? If I execute the query in Jaspersoft I only get null values, although the table is filled with data.

Comment: If I replace `$VARIANT$` with `"01.01.1971"`  I get the table entries.

Comment: `$VARIANT$` is not any special mysql syntax; if this query was being run in jaspersoft, it must have been being replaced with some date there.  The date is going to determine which published data records are included in what the subquery returns.